# Android WebView: Don't invert images in dark theme

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

We are having a couple of WebViews in our app, and when trying to implement the dark theme we use the following settings:

```
WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(settings, WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON)
WebSettingsCompat.setForceDarkStrategy(settings, WebSettingsCompat.DARK_STRATEGY_PREFER_WEB_THEME_OVER_USER_AGENT_DARKENING)
```

The problem is that most of the pages doesn't have the dark web theme defined, so the user-agent darkening is used. Text content is working correctly, but if there are images in the web content their colors are inverted as well, resulting in a really strange look.

Is there any option to exclude images from the user-agent darkening? I haven't found any documentation about this in the official docs.